# Converting string to dictionary from a opened file

Tags: python-3.x

A text file contains dictionary as below

```json
{
 "A":"AB","B":"BA"
}
```

Below are code of python file

```python
with open('devices_file') as d:
 print (d["A"])
```

Result should print `AB`.

Comment: Look into [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which allows you to obtain a python object from a string.

Comment: If the file is basically JSON they could use `json.loads()` as well.

Comment: Please find out what format your data is in. This could be either of JSON or Python notation.

Answer (score 2):

As @rassar and @Ivrf suggested in comments you can use `ast.literal_eval()` as well as `json.loads()` to achieve this. Both code snippets outputs `AB`.

Solution with `ast.literal_eval()`:

```python
import ast

with open("devices_file", "r") as d:
    content = d.read()
    result = ast.literal_eval(content)

print(result["A"])
```

Solution with `json.loads()`:

```python
import json

with open("devices_file") as d:
    content = json.load(d)

print(content["A"])
```

Python documentation about [ast.eval_literal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.load).

---

*Also:* I noticed that you're not using the correct syntax in the code snippet in your question. Indented lines should be indented with 4 spaces, and between the `print` keyword and the associated parentheses there's no whitespace allowed.

Comment: Note that ``json.loads`` and ``ast.literal_eval`` are not equivalent. One should use the correct one depending on the format of the data.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Unfortunately I'm not very experienced in Python and still learning. Which one would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Neither. One has to know the format of one's data. If the question asker does not specify the format, there is no way to know from the snippet.

Comment: The OP wrote that it's a plain text file containing a `dict`. Wouldn't be `ast.eval_literal` appropriate in this case?

Comment: This is a problem that comes up often. Usually, people don't know that there is a difference between a Python literal and JSON. It helps to explicitly ask for confirmation.

Comment: @VigneshwarKarunagaran Great, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the hook symbol under the vote count.